# Type Decimal doesn't work in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I created a table in Redshift:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table1 (
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  longitude decimal(6,4)
);
```

and inserted:

```
INSERT INTO test_table1 VALUES (1, 65.3695);
```

yet querying the database shows `(1, 65.37)`

[image: see an image here]

Why isn't the result:  `1, 65.3695`?

Comment: Which tool are you using to display that? It's probably just a configuration on how that tool formats numbers. Check the manual of your SQL client

Comment: I am using SQL Workbench/J

Comment: http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/options.html#options-decimal-digits

Comment: thx, probles was in configuration SQL Workbench/J !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a display parameter in SQL Workbench.
Tools > Options... > Data Formatting > Decimal digits